# R - how to apply as.POSIX for time with large number of decimal places

Tags: r, lapply, posixct

I have the following date time format(`startime` and  `stoptime`):

```
objectid                     endtime                   starttime
1     310822 2020-09-07T00:00:00.0000000 2020-09-06T00:00:00.0000000
2     310821 2020-09-06T19:34:40.0000000 2020-09-06T19:33:21.0000000
3     310820 2020-09-06T19:32:09.0000000 2020-09-06T19:31:22.0000000
4     310819 2020-09-06T19:31:12.0000000 2020-09-06T19:30:31.0000000
5     310818 2020-09-06T19:29:16.0000000 2020-09-06T19:28:12.0000000
6     310817 2020-09-06T19:27:55.0000000 2020-09-06T19:27:09.0000000
7     310816 2020-09-06T19:25:03.0000000 2020-09-06T19:22:51.0000000
```

There are a lot of decimal places(it this is the correct term) after seconds, hence the time is very precise.

I am trying to apply the as.POSIX with the following code:

```
# grabs starttime and endtime
cols = grep( "time$", names(dataset), value = TRUE )

dataset[, (cols) := lapply( .SD, as.POSIXct, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), .SDcols = cols ]
```

However I always get the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(dataset, , `:=`((cols), lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct,  : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = cols)
```

I have figured is something wrong with my `format` : `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"`, how should I correctly format the date & time in the data above?

If there's no better way, how can I clean the data to rid off the decimal places after seconds?

Comment: Are you sure you are applying the same code as shown? Your code looks good to me. Can you provide your data using `dput(head(dataset))` ?

Comment: Maybe you have a dataframe (from the error message) and not data.table hence the data.table syntax fails. Run `setDT(dataset)` and try your code again.